# Only get files from current date

Tags: powershell, where-clause

this may be very easy for the most Powershell programmers, but im completly new into powershell and getting frustrated by a simple Where-Object query.

I collecting csv from a folder:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $home\desktop\test\*.csv -Recurse
```

So the output is like this:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                  
-a----       01.09.2020     11:38             16 a.csv                                                                          
-a----       01.09.2020     11:38             10 b.csv                                                                              
-a----       31.08.2020     13:39             10 c.csv                                                                              
-a----       01.09.2020     11:38             14 d.csv                                                                          
-a----       31.08.2020     13:39             14 e.csv                                                                          
-a----       31.08.2020     13:38             16 f.csv                                                                        
-a----       31.08.2020     13:40             17 g.csv
```

And so on.. so far so good. But now i want just the .csv files that matches the current date. So for my understandings i have to do:

```
$date = $(get-date)
$files2 = $files | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -eq $date)}
```

But the result in the variable files2 is empty. I dont know why :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Powershell will represent `LastWriteTime` like a string when writing to host, `LastWriteTime` is actually of type `DateTime`.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $home\desktop\test\*.csv -Recurse
$files.LastWriteTime[0].GetType()
```

Which means that, in turn, your where clause is saying "Get all the files where LastWriteTime equals the current time", where current time is the exact moment that you ran Get-Date. Obviously this is always going to be nothing unless you happen to write a file at the exact same moment, or play around with your system time, or some other edge case.

To fix this, get a DateTime object and set the time to the beginning of the day, like so:

```
$date = (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0 -Millisecond 0)
```

Then, search for files where the `LastWriteTime` is *greater than* this value.

```
$files2 = $files | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -gt $date)}
```

Full script should look like this:

```
$date = (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0 -Millisecond 0)
$files = Get-ChildItem $home\desktop\test\*.csv -Recurse
$files2 = $files | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $date}
$files2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So i was already close but yet so far.. Thanks for the explanation. Now i know how to handle the get-date a little bit better :)